# Parse string for CSS properties - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I have to parse through this Javascript string to increase font-size, line-height, and width, because the text is currently too small for our mobile users. Unfortunately, I have no control over this awful mess of a string, and as such, cannot modify the input in any way. I'm hacking through an old iFrame, essentially.

```
nftext=new String(''+
'<html>'+
'<head>'+
'<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">'+
'<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">'+
'<style type="text/css">'+
'html,body {height:100%; width:100%; overflow:hidden; }'+
'   html {overflow:hidden; border:solid black 1pt;}'+
'   body {margin:0px; padding:0px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:8pt;}'+
'   td   {font-size: 8pt;}'+
'</style>'+
'</head>'+
'<body>'+
'<div style="position:relative; border:solid black 1pt; '+
'     padding-top:2px; padding-left:3px; padding-right:2px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-left:1px; margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-right:1px;">'+
'<table valign="top" style="width:210px; padding:0px; border-collapse:collapse; margin:0px;">'+
'<tr>'+
'<td style="padding:0px; width:11px; font-size:1px;"></td>'+
'<td style="padding:0px; width:42px; font-size:1px;"></td>'+
'<td style="padding:0px; width:32px; font-size:1px;"></td>'+
'<td style="padding:0px; width:32px; font-size:1px;"></td>'+
'<td style="padding:0px; width:32px; font-size:1px;"></td>'+
'<td style="padding:0px; width:29px; font-size:1px;"></td>'+
'<td style="padding:0px; width:32px; font-size:1px;"></td>'+
'</tr>'+c1+' NUTRITION FACTS '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=7>'+
'<span style="font-size:17pt; letter-spacing:'+((browserType=="firefox")?'2.5px;':'2.25px;')+
' line-height:80%; margin-top:-10px; text-align:justify;"><b style="font-weight:600;">Nutrition Facts</b></span></td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' SERVING SIZE '+c2+
'<tr><td colspan=7 style="line-height:10.0pt; border-bottom:solid black 8pt;">Serving Size ~servsize~</td></tr>'+
c1+' AMOUNT PER SERVING '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=7 style="font-size:6.0pt; line-height:6.0pt; border-bottom:solid black 1pt;"><b>Amount per Serving</b></td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' CALORIES / CALORIES FROM FAT '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=3 style="line-height:10.0pt; border-bottom:solid black 3pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">Calories</b> ~c~</td>'+
'<td colspan=4 align=right style="line-height:10.0pt; border-bottom:solid black 3pt;">Calories from Fat ~cf~</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' DAILY VALUE '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=7 align=right style="font-size:6.0pt; line-height:6.0pt; border-bottom:solid black 1pt;"><b>% Daily Value</b></td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' TOTAL FAT '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=4 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt"><b style="font-weight:600;">Total Fat</b> ~fat~g</td>'+
'<td colspan=3 align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">~fatp~</b>%</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' SAT FAT '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td style="width:11px; line-height:10pt;">&nbsp;</td>'+
'<td colspan=4 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">Saturated Fat ~sfat~g</td>'+
'<td colspan=2 align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">~sfatp~</b>%</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' TRANS FAT '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td style="width:11px; line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">&nbsp;</td>'+
'<td colspan=6 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><i>Trans</i> Fat ~tfat~</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' CHOLESTEROL '+c2+
'<tr >'+
'<td colspan=4 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">Cholesterol</b> ~chl~mg</td>'+
'<td colspan=3 align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">~chp~</b>%</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' SODIUM '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=4 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">Sodium</b> ~sod~mg</td>'+
'<td colspan=3 align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">~sodp~</b>%</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' TOTAL CARBOHYDRATES '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=6 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">Total Carbohydrates</b> ~b~g</td>'+
'<td align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt"><b style="font-weight:600;">~bp~</b>%</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' DIETARY FIBER '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td style="line-height:10pt;">&nbsp;</td>'+
'<td colspan=4 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">Dietary Fiber ~df~g</td>'+
'<td colspan=2 align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b style="font-weight:600;">~dfp~</b>%</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' SUGARS '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">&nbsp;</td>'+
'<td colspan=6 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">Sugars ~sug~g</span></td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' PROTEIN '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=7 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 8.0pt;"><b>Protein</b> ~pro~g</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' VIT A/VIT C '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=3 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">Vitamin A ~a~%</td>'+
'<td align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b>&bull;</b>&nbsp;</td>'+
'<td colspan=3 align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">Vitamin C ~cp~%</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' CALCIUM/IRON '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td colspan=3 style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">Calcium ~up~%</td>'+
'<td align=right style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;"><b>&bull;</b>&nbsp;</td>'+
'<td colspan=3 align="right" style="line-height:10pt; border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;">Iron ~ip~%</td>'+
'</tr>'+
c1+' BASED ON '+c2+
'<tr>'+
'<td align=center valign=top style="line-height:8.0pt; padding-top:2px;">*</td>'+
'<td valign=top colspan=6 style="font-size:6.5pt; line-height:8.0pt; padding-top:2px;">Percent Daily Values are based on a 2,000 '+
'calorie diet.</td></tr></table></div>'+
'<div style="height:77px; font-size:7.5pt; line-height: 120%; margin-left:4px; margin-right:4px; margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:1px; vertical-align:top;">'+
'<b>~rname~</b><div style="line-height: 120%; font-size:7pt; margin-left:1px; margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:2px;">~rdesc~</div></div>'+
'<div style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:5px; right:2px; bottom:13px; font-size:7pt; color:#800000;">~allergen~</div>'+
'<div style="z-index: 0; position:absolute; text-align:center; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; width:100%; font-size:7pt; color:#fff; background-color:#000; ">Move mouse or press Escape key to close</div>'+
'</body></html>');
```

Is there a set of regular expressions I can use to get what I need? Currently I use this overly-complex function I wrote that gives me unreliable results. It replaces some properties correctly, but for others, it will skip over replacing them because it starts after the first letter of the property (example: 'ine-height:' and 'ont-size:').

```
function findAndReplaceProperty( baseString, propertyName, replaceWith ){


 var indices = getMatchIndexes(baseString, propertyName);

    //replace each property
    for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){

        //get original string
        var beginningOfWord = indices[i]; //word starts here
        var endOfWord = baseString.indexOf( ';' , beginningOfWord ); //css values always end at a semicolon

        //actually grab css property
        var strOriginal = baseString.substring(beginningOfWord, endOfWord+1);


        //remove extraneous junk
        strOriginal = strOriginal.replace('{', '');
        strOriginal = strOriginal.replace('=', '');
        strOriginal = strOriginal.replace('"', '');
        strOriginal = strOriginal.trim();


        //if strOriginal actually matches the property we want to replace
        //replace it
        if (replaceWith.substring(0,1) == strOriginal.substring(0,1)) {
         console.log('replacing ' + strOriginal + ' with ' + replaceWith);
         baseString = baseString.replace(strOriginal, replaceWith);
        }
        else{
         console.log('did not replace ' + strOriginal);
        }


    }
    return baseString;
}

//function getMatchIndexes from StackOverflow
function getMatchIndexes(str, toMatch) {
    var toMatchLength = toMatch.length,
        indexMatches = [], match,
        i = 0;

    while ((match = str.indexOf(toMatch, i)) > -1) {
        indexMatches.push(match);
        i = match + toMatchLength;
    }

    return indexMatches;
}
```

Comment: OH my. Why not defining your html,body to 10px, and everything else in em's? 15px -> 1.5em. All you have to do is set the body to 11px to increase everything

Answer (score 0):

first extract content of style tag:

```
/\<style[^>]*\>([^<]+)\</
```

then match style for each element:

```
/([a-zA-Z,]+)[\s\n\r]+\{([^}]+)\}/
```

then for each result match all:

```
/([a-z]+)\s*:\s*([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\s*;/
```

Answer (score 0):

Screw it - after spending way too much time on this, I've decided to use this method. It's not...ideal, but it works well enough.

```
var replaced = popup.replace(/font-size:6.0pt;/g, 'font-size: 1em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/font-size:6.5pt;/g, 'font-size: 1.25em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/font-size:7pt;/g, 'font-size: .75em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/font-size:7.5pt;/g, 'font-size: 1.5em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/font-size:8pt;/g, 'font-size: 2em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/font-size: 8pt;/g, 'font-size: 2em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/font-size:17pt;/g, 'font-size: 3em;');

//increase width
replaced = replaced.replace(/width:210px;/g, 'width:800px;');

//increase line-height
replaced = replaced.replace(/line-height:6pt;/g, 'line-height:1em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/line-height:6.0pt;/g, 'line-height:1em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/line-height:8pt;/g, 'line-height:1.25em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/line-height:8.0pt;/g, 'line-height:1.25em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/line-height:10pt;/g, 'line-height:1.5em;');
replaced = replaced.replace(/line-height:10.0pt;/g, 'line-height:1.5em;');

console.log('final html: ' + replaced);
```